# How to elegantly find rotation of SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode that is continually rotating by running an SKAction on it. Right now I am trying to determine its position at any given time based on its speed of rotation and how much time has elapsed since it started, but this seems a bit jenky. It seems like there should be some way of finding the rotation of an SKSpriteNode at any given time, but the only property for that seems to be zRotation, which is along the z-axis. Does anyone have an idea of how I can approach this in a better way?

Comment: `zRotation` is almost certainly what you want.  The z-axis is perpendicular to the screen, and rotation around that axis is what spins the sprite in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks. I automatically dismissed zRotation because I imaged that something rotating flat on the screen would only involve changes in x and y, but now that I think about it as rotating "around" the z-axis it makes much more sense. I should have just tried it out and I would have seen that it worked. Thanks for your time.